# iFrame window.postMessage - data is always an empty string

Tags: javascript, postmessage

I am trying to post a message to an iFrame within my angular application. The message makes it to the iFrame; however, the data passed is always received as an empty string in the iFrame.

Any ideas why this could be?

Note: both of the applications are running locally.

In my angular application:

**html**:

```
<iframe id="authIFrame" src="http://127.0.0.1:9000"></iframe>
```

**ts**:

```
const wn = document.getElementById('authIFrame').contentWindow;
wn.postMessage({authToken: 'abcdefg'},  '*');
```

In the iFrame:

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('message', handleMessage, false);
  } else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onmessage', handleMessage());
  }

  function handleMessage(event) {
 //HERE>>>>  event.data is always "" (empty string)
    const {data, origin, source} = event;

    if (isOriginAllowed(origin)) {

      const {method, accessToken, idToken, userData} = data;

      if (method === 'SET') {
        return setIdentityData(accessToken, idToken, userData);
      } else if (method === 'GET') {
        return getIdentityData();
      }
    }
  }
```

I also tried stringifying the data passed to the iFrame. It didn't help.

My only guess is that maybe the browser is refusing the send the data since my app is not running over https...

Comment: I also tried stringifying the data passed to the iFrame. It didn't help.

Comment: Shouldn't target be the the other localhost your application is running on ?

Comment: yes. i updated it. still having the same issue though.

Comment: Did you find an answer? I face the same issue in the Firefox browser on production but can not reproduce locally.

Answer (score 0):

Your data always empty before load iframe ,just send data after loaded your iframe

```
authIFrame.addEventListener('load',()=>{
    //your code paste  here
})
```

Comment: The author said his iframe received the message alright. If the iframe wasn't loaded, he wouldn't have got the event.

Comment: @DanMacák yet thanks to your 10K+ rep, **you** can see it's the issue OP was facing, as they said in their now deleted answer. Wanna help close this has "no repro"? The problem as being described can't be reproduced.

Comment: @Kaiido truly, I overlooked the deleted answer (thanks to its disqualifying styling).